# Как программно узнать, что устройство работает в режиме Wi-Fi точки доступа?

Tags: java, android, wifi

Как можно средствами Java узнать, что телефон находиться в режиме "точка доступа"?

Мне необходимо узнать, раздаёт ли телефон Wi-Fi / подключен ли к нему.

Вот код на проверку подключения к Wi-Fi:

```
public boolean isWiFiOn() {
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(wifi != null)
        switch(wifi.getWifiState()) {
            case(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED):
            case(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING):
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Но этот код возвращает `false`, если телефон в режиме точки доступа.

Как в таком случае узнать, раздаёт ли он Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Официально узнать нельзя, но Android на то и "андроид", что много чего можно сделать при помощи хаков:
Есть спрятанный `@hide` метод `getWifiApState`:

```
Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getWifiApState");
method.setAccessible(true);
int actualState = (Integer) method.invoke(wifiManager, (Object[]) null);
```

Далее `actualState` сравниваем с такими константами:

```
public static int WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLING = 10; //выключается
public static int WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLED = 11;  //выключен
public static int WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING = 12;  //включается
public static int WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED = 13;   //включен
public static int WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED = 14;    //сломалсо
```

UPD: [ссылка](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java#WifiManager.getWifiApState%28%29) на метод в исходниках:

Comment: Спасибо. А константы в каком классе?

Comment: Решил другой метод использовать: isWifiApEnabled. Собственно то же самое но проверку он сам проводит. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, константы в том же классе, но они скрыты, и вам придется их в любом случае скопировать в свой класс.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, есть шанс, что isWifiApEnabled покажет неправильный результат, т. к. он проверяет состояние только на AP_STATE_ENABLED, и не проверяет на *включается* и *сломалсо*, а это может стать проблемой

Comment: только константы всё же начинаються с WIFI_AP_STATE

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, и правда. Сейчас отредактирую.